# How to live stream video on twitter

Tags: twitter, live-streaming, twitter-api-v2, twitter-anywhere, twitter-api-v1

We are working on platform where we allow user to live-stream on major platforms. We need to integrate twitter in our platform to stream live on twitter.

currently we are creating source and broadcast by making post call to /source and /broadcast endpoints of twitter API and then a put call to /broadcast endpoint which will make the broadcast live.

Now this endpoints are deprecated and not working. And no alternative is available on official documentation.

We need the process guide and APIs we can use to stream live on twitter.

Comment: Twitter is in-flux so much these days, I'm not sure I'd depend on any endpoints being stable, for what it's worth.

Answer (score -2):

To integrate live streaming on Twitter into your platform, you can follow these steps:

1. Set up a Twitter Developer Account: If you haven't already, create a
   developer account on the Twitter Developer Portal
   (developer.twitter.com) and apply for a developer API key.
2. Create a Twitter App: Once your developer account is set up, create
   a new Twitter application. Provide the required details, such as
   name, description, and website URL for your platform.
3. Obtain API Keys and Access Tokens: After creating your Twitter app,
   you'll receive API keys (API key and secret) and access tokens
   (access token and secret). These credentials are necessary for
   authenticating your requests to the Twitter API.
4. Implement OAuth Authorization: To allow users to grant your platform
   access to their Twitter accounts, you need to implement the OAuth
   authorization process. This involves redirecting users to Twitter's
   authorization URL, obtaining their consent, and receiving an OAuth
   token.
5. Initiate the Live Stream: Once you have the necessary user
   permissions, you can use Twitter's Media APIs to initiate a live
   stream. You can make a POST request to the statuses/update endpoint
   with the media_ids parameter set to the media ID of your live
   stream.
6. Broadcast the Live Stream: To actually broadcast the live stream,
   you need to use a streaming server that supports the Real-Time
   Messaging Protocol (RTMP). Set up an RTMP server and configure it to
   accept the live stream from your users.
7. Connect to the RTMP Server: Use a streaming library or software
   development kit (SDK) to connect to the RTMP server and send your
   live stream data. Ensure that you encode the video and audio streams
   according to Twitter's specifications.
8. Monitor and Handle Stream Events: Twitter provides a variety of
   stream event callbacks that you can subscribe to. These callbacks
   notify you of events like when the stream starts, when viewers
   interact with the stream, or when the stream ends. Implement
   appropriate event handling in your platform.

Remember to refer to the official Twitter API documentation (developer.twitter.com/en/docs) for detailed information and any specific updates or changes to the API endpoints.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, AmmarTech.

This answer also appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). As I mentioned a few weeks ago on your previous answer, [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

We do hope you'll be a part of our community and contribute with *your own*, quality posts in the future. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.